# Need to click a button in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

HTML CODE

```
<button class="slds-button slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-3 slds-medium-size--1-of-4 slds-large-size--1-of-12 slds-button--neutral" ng-click="changePipelineView('Acquisition', 'building', '', 'Building Acquisition')">Bldg Acq.</button>
```

unable to click this element help with your suggestions ...

Comment: Unable to click means what ? getting any error ? what did you tried can you show your effort ?

Comment: i am getting the error : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(text(),'Bldg Acq')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)

Comment: already i posted my error and issue which im facing dont give inappropriate comments

Comment: is your element in iframe ?

Comment: yes it is in iframe .

Comment: First you need to switch into iframe using `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` then perform click

Comment: ok i will try..

Answer (score 1):

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Bldg Acq')]")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
driver.findElement(By.className("slds-button")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the button is in a different frame or on the main body